# Anaconda activate/deactivate cycle messes up PATH

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda on my Debian installation and configured the `PATH` variable on my .zshenv file so the `python` executable is the one from the system:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/bin/anaconda3/bin
```

If I check which `python` executable is being used I get the right one:

```
> which python
/usr/bin/python
```

If I activate a conda env, I get the `python` executable from the environment:

```
> source activate test
discarding /home/user/bin/anaconda3/bin from PATH
prepending /home/user/bin/anaconda3/envs/test/bin to PATH
> which python
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python
```

Ok, not exactly what I wanted, but it is what is supposed to be. Now I deactivate the environment:

```
> source deactivate
discarding /home/user/bin/anaconda3/envs/test/bin from PATH
```

so now I expected that my `python` executable would the the system again, but no:

```
> which python
/home/user/bin/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python
```

Is there a way to configure anaconda to not do that? Is this a bug?

Comment: Fixed. Found a bug report about it: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1846